# Normal distribution problem. How to solve this question?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose that the middle 68% of speeding ticket fines on a highway fall between 96.75 and 122.31. Give an approximate estimate of the standard deviation of the speeding ticket fines. Assume the fine amount has a normal distribution.

A. 109.53

B. 6.39

C. -12.78

D. 12.78

E. 25.56

I am thinking.

(Lower + upper )/2 = (96.75+122.31)/2 = 109.53

But I am not sure, any help?

Comment: One does not "solve" a question, one "answers" a question.

Comment: @Mark viola, So, I think 1 is answer according empirical rule?

Comment: @Mark Viola sir, can u please explain how  it comes?

Comment: @Mak Viola, Thank you sir, if you type as a answer ,I will accept it .

Comment: @Mark Viola, sir but which logic we use here? Why we subtract ? Sorry . I really want to understand.

Comment: How is the standard deviation defined?  For a normal distribution, what is the probability of being between (1) the mean minus one standard deviation ($\mu-\sigma$) and (2) the mean plus one standard deviation ($\mu+\sigma$)?  So, if the mean is the median, which it is for a normal distribution, then the "middle" is the mean, $\mu$.  So, the answer is actually $$\frac{122.31-96.75}{2}=12.78$$

Comment: @Mark Viola, thats correct answer. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the $1-2-3$ rule, in a Normally-distributed population, $68\% , 95\%, 99.7 \% $ inof all data falls within $1-2-3$ standard deviations of the mean. You are given the lower and upper ends of that $68\%$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: I know using empirical rule 68% of data lie within 1 standard deviation from the mean, but I am stuck on following option, any help, which one is correct?

Comment: Then you know 122.31 is +one SD from the mean and 96.75 is -one SD from the mean. Then their difference (122.31-96.75)=25.56 is 2SD from the mean, so SD=$\frac {1}{2}25.56=12.78$.